# Ruby on Rails - Multibutton combined with checkboxes and advanced search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, button

Currently I have the situation that one button is add to the index-form. This workes perfectly in combination with the other functionalties as search and checkboxes which are also part of the index-form.

Code of the `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag order_path, :method => 'get' do %>    
    <p>
      <%= submit_tag "Historical Search", :account_short => nil %>
       <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    </p> 
<% end %>

<%= form_tag sendnext_order_path, :method => :put do %>
    <%= submit_tag "Send to Desk" %><br/>
    -- other code from index-form
<% end %>
```

Combined with the `controller`:

```
def sendnext
    Order.update_all(["status_id = ? ", "2"], :id => params[:order_ids])
    redirect_to order_path, notice: 'Order succesfully send to desk.'
 end
```

Now I want to add a second button next to the `Send to Desk` button with another action than the excisting working one. Until now I'm not capable to realise this.

Please advice. Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: It would help if you mention what other function you are trying to reach with the new button.

Comment: I have written the function in the controller which has the same methodology as `sendnext` and is called `cancelorder` which updates the status_id to "3".

Comment: So why not add another form for that button with cancelorder_order_path as long as you have a route for it?

Comment: I have done this exactly as you describe. The result is that both buttons will execute `sendnext` and none is executing `cancelorder`. I have duplicated the working `sendnext`.

Comment: `def cancelorder
    Order.update_all(["status_id = ? ", "3"], :id => params[:order_ids])
    redirect_to order_path, notice: 'Order succesfully cancelled.'
 end` is the code in the controller. In the index I have: <%= form_tag cancelorder_order_path, :method => :put do %>
    <%= submit_tag "Cancel Order" %><br/>
The route has copied the record with `  put 'cancelorder', :on => :collection   `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I have found a working solution which realised my current requirements:

The `index.html.erb` looks like the following:

```
<%= form_tag updateorder_order_path, :method => :put do %> 
   <%= submit_tag "To Desk" %><br/> 
   <%= submit_tag "Cancel Order" %> 

   -- other code like data fields

 <%end %>
```

The `controller.rb` looks like the following:

```
  def updateorder   
    if params[:commit] == "To Desk"
       Order.update_all(["status_id = ? ", "2"], :id => params[:order_ids])
       redirect_to order_path, notice: 'Order(s) successfully send to desk.'
    elsif params[:commit] == "Cancel Order"
       Order.update_all(["status_id = ? ", "3"], :id => params[:order_ids])
       redirect_to order_path, notice: 'Order(s) successfully cancelled.'
    else
       Order.update_all(["status_id = ? ", "5"], :id => params[:order_ids])
       redirect_to order_path, notice: 'Order(s) successfully updated.'
    end
  end
```

The `routes.rb` contains the next code:

```
     resources :orders do
        put 'updateorder', :on => :collection
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)

```
<%= button_to('Send to Desk', 'sendnext', :method => "put") %>
<%= button_to('Cancel Order', 'cancelorder ', :method => "put") %>
```

Will take care of the form for you.  `submit_tag` is submitting the first form I believe.

For example

```
<%= button_to "New", :action => "new" %>
```

will generate

```
# => "<form method="post" action="/controller/new" class="button_to">
#      <div><input value="New" type="submit" /></div>
#    </form>"
```

Comment: Thanks... I have tried this and receive the error: `No route matches [PUT] "/sendnext"`. The routes I had working for one button is:`        resources :orders do
            put 'sendnext', :on => :collection
            put 'cancelorder', :on => :collection
         end `